# How to edit ActionBarSherlock navigation tab size

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

[image: Screenshot]

Please take a look at the image above. You can see that the navigation tabs in `Actionbar` of the Google Play market screenshot is like 2/3rd the size of `ActionbarSherlock` Samples/Styled application. I have searched and searched but couldn't find an attribute that can change this. So how can I decrease the size of these nav tabs. It looks like a pretty easy way of saving some screen real estate.

Comment: Did you got anything to change the Height of the Navigation tab? I am using the Android SherlockActionBar with navigation Tabs and need to reduce the height of the navigation tabs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is not action bar tabs. That is an indicator for use with a `ViewPager`.

There is a rudimentary implementation of this in the support library (`PagerTitleStrip`) but it leaves A LOT to be desired. You should take a look at http://viewpagerindicator.com for a much more comprehensive implementation.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right way. I implemented 'PagerTitleStrip' and got the desired effect. I'll add 'ViewPagerIndicator' when it's need occurs.

Comment: Hmm. It seems like Play does not use PagerTitleStrip. It uses PagerTabStrip. See : https://plus.google.com/118292708268361843293/posts/Et4c4b9h6AF . Does ABS support rev 9 of the support library yet?

Comment: @BinoyBabu No, Jake is right. It's definitely a PagerTitleStrip used in the Play Store. That link has nothing to do with it. You should accept this answer.

Comment: @PaulBurke You're right. http://pastebin.com/6ygfuKV8 . However I can acheive the same effect much easily with PagerTabStrip.